# Query orders from other sites in Commerce Cloud

Tags: commerce-cloud, order, e-commerce

We are developing in Commerce Cloud 2 sites, one to be viewed on a desktop browser, and another to be viewed on a webview inside a react-native app.

We are using `OrderMgr.searchOrders()` to fetch the customer's orders but, since we have 2 different sites, each site only sees their respective orders.

Is there a way to fetch the orders from both sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These orders are separated; you can do a workaround by calling the OCAPI/SCAPI endpoints to the other site.

Generally, for APPs, there is no need to set up a separate site, but you probably have a valid business case to have a separate one.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue.